# Offset does not work for horizontal positioning (when passed due an Array) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, offset

I got a problem with an Offset in VBA. I want a resulting position to be dynamic, depending on a String in an Array.

```vb
Sub MoveText()

  Dim R(0) As String 
  R(0) = "0,1"

  Cells(1, 1).Offset(R(0)).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

In this example I would like to write the Value of `A1` to `A2`. However, the horizontally movement is not being fulfilled.

I really hope, someone can tell me the difference, why one of the inputs does work usually while one does not.

Comment: Hi. offset is expecting 1 or 2 parameters as integers, and ignores the values after de comma. when u put "0,1", it does nothing, because is moving 0 cols. If "0,1" represents cols and rows, u must separate them (with a split), an user the two variables in the offset

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused about the ability to read a String like "1,0" but the the Offset also just read the first Digit and i just did not realize it.

Comment: You would have to use something like `Cells(1, 1).Offset(Split(R(0), ",")(0), Split(R(0), ",")(1)).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value` which is rather inefficient and unreadable. A better attempt would be to make the array two-dimensional e.g. the first column containing the row, and the second containing the column offset. If you could clarify how you mean to use it, you would surely get some decent advice.

Comment: Hi, thank you. In the end i just passed two Integers to the Offset like Cells(1, 1).Offset(row, column).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value. Your solution would even work with the String i used. I just did not get, that i only passed one value to the Offset(), when im using a simple string. It seems strange to me, that VBA is able to search for an Integer in the string (so it would get the numbers of the beginning of the string) and simply ignore the remaining part of the String without any mismatch-error